# Why can't you UnRegisterStartupScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, clientscript

Seems to me it is a bit wierd that you can do..

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "KeyName", "alert('changed my mind')", true);
```

And then later on you can't unregister or stop the javascript from being rendered programatically.

Why would Microsoft do this?

I don't like the work around here..
http://hemant-vikram.blogspot.com/2005/11/unregister-startup-script-workaround.html

And I don't like the option of just re-registering it and having it do nothing..

Thoughts?

Comment: Just out of interest's sake, **why** would you want to unregister a script?

Comment: @Ian: because if you go to another web page and back again using the browser's BACK option, the script re-runs again!

Comment: @IanKemp In my case it was because I needed to launch a popup, but only after the postback occured.  Check my answer, while this whole problem is a kludge, this was by far the least kludgy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you'd want to "unregister" the script (which has already been registered) under some condition, like so:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "KeyName", "alert('changed my mind')", true);
...
if(condition)
    Page.ClientScript.UnregisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "KeyName", "alert('changed my mind')", true);
```

Why can't this simply be changed to:

```
if(!condition)
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "KeyName", "alert('changed my mind')", true);
```

Comment: You're right instead of fixing the code smell with refactoring I was looking for a faster solution.. naughty!

Comment: If only it were as deliberate as protecting you from calling Unregister too late. It's actually safe right up to the Render stage, but RegisterStartupScript is quite happy to be called after Render when it's too late to actually include the script in the response.

Answer (score 10):

It's actually worse than you think  - "just re-registering it and having it do nothing" isn't an option either. The register method checks if a script is already registered with that key, and does nothing if it is. Once you call `RegisterStartupScript`, nothing you can do will stop that script being rendered.

As to why Microsoft did that, I'd guess that the possibility of changing or removing registered scripts was simply forgotten when `RegisterStartupScript` was first designed. The design choices happened to make it non-trivial to go back and create an unregister method, so they'd now need a good reason to do that.

When you register a script, it's stored in two places within the ClientScriptManager. A ListDictionary allows checks for whether a script is already registered, and an ArrayList stores the actual scripts as they will be rendered. I assume that the ArrayList is used to ensure that scripts are rendered in the order in which they were registered, but it also means that you can't tell which string in the ArrayList belongs to which key.

It wouldn't be terribly hard to equip your own page class with methods for `MaybeAddStartupScript(key,script)` and `ChangedMyMindAboutThatStartupScript(key)`. Store the keys and scripts in your own dictionary and then in PreRender, register whichever scripts made it this far. It's certainly annoying to have to do it yourself, though.

Comment: The key point I took from this answer was registering scripts in Pre_Render rather than registering in Page_Load and then attempting to re-register based on an event on the page.

Comment: @BrianHinchey I agree, and while my answer here doesnt use prerender, it helps to understand what is going on behind the scenes.  Take a look and tell me if you like my solution.

Answer (score 2):

After much studying, I found a solution to the problem if you want to *only run the registered script once* based on an event.  Special thanks to @stevemegson's answer here that helped me understand what the problem actually was.

The solution involves the `Sys.Application.add_load` and `remove_load` javascript methods.

It works like this.  A generic javascript function that first calls the worker function, then removes itself is the first statement, then `add_load` follows it up by calling that function:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var script = @"<script language='javascript'>
                       function f(){ MyWorkerFunction(); 
                                     Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}; 
                       Sys.Application.add_load(f);
               </script>";

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), 
                                   "MyWorkerFunctionKey", 
                                    script, 
                                    false);
}
```

This is based on a [telerik solution](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/window/details/calling-radalert-from-codebehind-%28all-versions-of-radwindow%29).  It references telerik controls, but all the functionality is ASP.NET.

Comment: This still causes the script to run again on post back for me

Comment: @JamesWierzba Unless you are putting this in page load, this will execute then immediately unload this method.  Perhaps you could duplicate your problem on a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

[How do I overwrite a Javascript function added (dynamically) by Asp.Net UpdatePanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121881/how-do-i-overwrite-a-javascript-function-added-dynamically-by-asp-net-updatepa)

I think an using updatepanel is one of solution to overwrite js. When we use update panel a JavaScript is not run on partial post back and must be registered by code:

```
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(someFunciton);
```

If we do not this then we can register/render a modified function again on partial post back in update panel. In such case are some problem with scope of function.

Sorry for my English.