# Appending an OnClick Event to an Existing JavaScript Button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I'm looking to append some JavaScript to the `onclick` of a button on the server side. So something like

```
 //b is a button
 b.Attributes.Add("onclick", "my.js.here();");
```

but without eliminating any potentially existing `onclick` event on that button.

EDIT: The above represents a codebehind file (in C#) that attempts to add an additional event listener to a client side button that already might have an `onclick` event.

Comment: There is only one `onclick` event, and only one bit of code that can be executed on that event.  Perhaps you could join on a parent object and get the bubble up event, but that doesnt work for every object/call.

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to register a javascript click event in codebehind?

Comment: Yes, codebehind. Sorry for the confusion. I modified the question to clarify.

Comment: Well, setting a click event in the codebehind is not difficult.  But you still dont get the option of keeping your existing clicks.  Only one task per click.

Comment: I believe that this answer i wrote will suit you.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22970430/2589202

Comment: That answers looks like exactly what I need...except that I'm using a simple `<input>` button, not an ASP.NET button. Without modifying the existing structure, is it possible to do the same thing?

Comment: Just set the input button to `runat="server"` give it an ID and it should work. (feel free to upvote it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally try to avoid subscribing to JavaScript events using attributes. Instead, I would opt for [`addEventListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) or some abstraction on top of that (like jQuery's .click handler). For example, continuing with the jQuery, you could use this JavaScript in your ASPX page:

```
$('#yourButtonId').click(function() {
      my.js.here();
 });
```

That has several advantages, the main of which you can add handlers without stomping on one that already exists.

You *could* try and do something like getting the attribute's existing value, then prepending it with `my.js.here();`, but that seems like a less-than-ideal solution.

Comment: Do you mean to call this JavaScript from the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method

```
$("#AuthorityLevel").find("a").attr('onclick','my.js.here();');
```